# JBoss AS 7 Module classloader WEB-INF lib

Tags: jboss, classloader, jboss7.x, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to configure my web application to jboss 7.1.1.Final. It turns out that using modules, then there is a moment that a class that is in a class module needs to access a folder that is inside the WEB-INF/lib of my war file. When this happens there is a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. I think the module classloader can not see classes in my WEB-INF/lib. How could I solve this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to access a directory (folder) in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory? Like `WEB-INF/lib/mydir`.

Comment: Thanks for answer James. I would like that the module access the classes inside my libs from my war file. This is possible? the module classloader can view the classes inside my web-inf/lib?

Comment: It will find JAR's in there, but classes that are not packaged in a JAR then then need to go in `WEB-INF/classes`.